# Gitlab with Docker won't update

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm currently using Gitlab using Docker. The container is using the latest image for Gitlab, but the admin area shows me a different version. How can I use the latest one ? I don't understand why Gitlab shows me a different version of what I'm using. I tried `gitlab-ctl upgrade` command, with no effect.

Docker shows me the correct (latest) image

[image: Docker]

Administration shows me 11.1.4 (so, I can't benefit 11.4.0 features)

[image: Administration panel]

Am I doing thing wrong ? When updating, I just change the image version. Everything works well since months, but now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ! I solved my problem. I've mounted a volume on `/opt/gitlab`, and it seems the upgrade doesn't working when the folder already exists. Just don't mount a volume on this folder.

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#where-is-the-data-stored does not show at any time this folder should be mounted.